# how can i download my files from a git repository

Tags: git, github, download, project

I´ve just started with Git and build my first project with it. I´ve installed GitHub Dektop too and can sync this with GitHub.com. I read a lot in the extensive help of GitHub. Now i know, how to put my files **into** GitHub.
But i don´t find anything about how to get files **from** the repo, i.e. to send a link to others.

How can my project be downloaded?
Where can i read somethig about this? Is there any tutorial, that i understand? ;-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a link on your Github project page to download all files as a zip - you can share that direct link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly i would suggest going thru the github tutorial, its quick and simple.  answers most of the basic questions you'll have.

after you have your files setup in your working directory, open github, and either create a new branch from your master.

at that point will be able to select the new branch and commit your changes to your branch.

https://help.github.com/categories/bootcamp/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this command to keep your current branch uptodate with the origin:

```
git pull
```

Comment: from where i can do this? Terminal on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it. Must only call the site *https://github.com/UlliH/CoreDataTest* ;-)